# "continuously differentiable $\subseteq$ Lipshitz continuous" with $f(x) = x^2$

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

In the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity), it says: **continuously differentiable (i.e. class $C^1$) $\subseteq$ Lipshitz continuous**.

Consider the simplest example ($x,y\in \mathbb{R}$): $$f(x) = x^2$$

1. It is not Lipshitz continuous. The reason is we cannot find $L$, such that $$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\leq L$$
2. $f(x)$ is differentiable with $f'(x) = 2x$, which is continuous. Therefore $f(x) = x^2$ is continuous differentiable and is in class $C^1$

However, this inference violates the one in the wiki. I guess the second inference might me wrong **but why?**

Comment: "over a closed and bounded set"!!!

Comment: which one? could you make it clear? I know this property but have no idea how to use it exactly

Comment: @sleevechen Wiki says "We have the following chain of inclusions for functions over a **closed and bounded** subset of the real line".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over a compact connected set each $C^1$ function is Lipschitz continuous, because its derivative is bounded (Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem) by some constant. This is also the constant in the Lipschitz continuity - follows from the Mean value theorem.

Note: $f(x)=x^2$ is locally Lipschitz on $\mathbb R$.